# Step to prove that $\cos (n \arccos (x))$ is a polynomial of $n$-th degree

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

I am confronted to the same problem stated in [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486561/prove-that-cos-n-arccos-x-is-a-polynomial-of-n-th-degree), namely to prove that cos(arccos())  is a polynomial of  -th degree.

However to begin with I don't understand how

$$
\cos[n \arccos(x) + \arccos(x)] = \cos[n \arccos(x)] \cos[\arccos(x)] - \sin[n \arccos(x)] \sin[\arccos(x)]
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $x=n\arccos(x)$ and $y=\arccos(x)$. Then $\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$. This a simple trigonometric identity. You can find a possible proof at http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m100/trigId.pdf, but just search for it and you get many variants.